# I am a south African with indefinate leave to remain UK visa. Can I travel with my British children to EEA country without a visa?

Tags: schengen, uk, italy

I am a south African with a indefinite leave to remain visa, married to a British citizen and have British citizen children. I am planing to go on holiday to Italy with my children only can I travel with my children without a visa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having a UK indefinite leave to remain has nothing to do in this case, only the passport you have determines if you need a Schengen visa or not and since you have a South African passport you'll need to apply for a Schengen visa in advance.

Sources:

- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3AIndefinite_leave_to_remain)
- [theschengenoffice.com](http://www.theschengenoffice.com/faq.html)